# If $T_n \rightarrow T$ uniformly at each bounded part of $\mathbb{R}^m$ then $T_n\rightarrow T$ in $\mathscr{L}(\mathbb{R}^m;E)$

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces

> Let $E$ normed vector space. The following affirmations about a sequence of linear transformations $T_n: \mathbb{R^m}\rightarrow E$ and $T\in \mathscr{L}(\mathbb{R^m};E)$ are equivalent:
>
> a) $\lim T_n\cdot x = T\cdot x$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R^m}$
>
> b) $\lim T_n\cdot e_i = T\cdot e_i$ for every $i=1,\cdots,m$ where $e_i$ denotes elements of the canonical basis.
>
> c) $T_n\rightarrow T$ uniformly for each bounded part of $\mathbb{R^m}$
>
> d) $T_n \rightarrow T$ in $\mathscr{L}(\mathbb{R^m};E)$

Well, of course $a)\implies b)$ as a particular case.

$b)\implies c):$

Let $x\in X$, and write $x=x_1e_1+\cdots +x_me_m.$ Since $X$ is bounded, it is $\|x\|<k$.  Given $\epsilon>0$, since $\lim T_n\cdot e_i = T\cdot e_i$ for every $i$, we may find $n_1,\cdots n_m$ naturals such that $(\cdots)$. Take $N=\mbox{max}\{n_1,\cdots,n_m\}$. Then, for every $n>N$ we have: \begin{align}\|(T_n-T)\cdot (x_1e_1+\cdots +x_m e_m)\| &= \|x_1(T_n-T)\cdot e_1+\cdots +x_m (T_n-T)\cdot e_m\|\\&<\frac{\epsilon}{k}(|x_1|+\cdots+|x_m|)<\epsilon\end{align}

which shows that $\|(T_n-T)\cdot x\|<\epsilon $ for every $n>N$ and $x\in X$

But i'm struggling to prove $c)\implies d)$ part (and of course $d)\implies a)$ also). I'm not very familiar with the usual metric for linear operators: $\|T\| = \mbox{sup}\{\|T\cdot x\|:x\in\mathbb{R^m},\|x\|=1\}$

Any help on how to prove this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c) $\implies$ d) :

Let $K$ be the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^m$. Then $T_n|_K$ converges uniformly to $T|_K$. So, given $\varepsilon>0$ there is some $p\in\mathbb N$ such that:$$(\forall n\in\mathbb{N})(\forall x\in K):\bigl\|T(x)-T_n(x)\bigr\|<\varepsilon.$$But then $\|T-T_n\|<\varepsilon$, and this proves that $\lim_{n\to\infty}T_n=T$ in $\mathscr{L}(\mathbb{R}^m;E)$.

d) $\implies$ a) :

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$. I will prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}T_n(x)=T(x)$. In order to do that, it is enough to note that$$\bigl\|T(x)-T_n(x)\bigr\|\leqslant\|T-T_n\|.\|x\|$$and that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|T-T_n\|=0$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Things were not so difficult after all!